# Need guidance implementing MTZ for k-TSP algorithm

Tags: python, pulp

I have successfully implemented code for MTZ approach to the TSP algorithm via pulp library. But now I'm trying to implement the same approach for k-TSP i.e when k salespeople are traversing the graph but i'm stumped over there

This is what I have implemented for the MTZ approach to the TSP problem.

```
from pulp import *

def mtz_encoding_tsp(n, cost_matrix):
    assert len(cost_matrix) == n, f'Cost matrix is not {n}x{n}'
    assert all(len(cj) == n for cj in cost_matrix), f'Cost matrix is not {n}x{n}'
    # create our encoding variables
    binary_vars = [ # add a binary variable x_{ij} if i not = j else simply add None
        [ LpVariable(f'x_{i}_{j}', cat='Binary') if i != j else None for j in range(n)] 
        for i in range(n) ]
    # add time stamps for ranges 1 .. n (skip vertex 0 for timestamps)
    time_stamps = [LpVariable(f't_{j}', lowBound=0, upBound=n, cat='Continuous') for j in range(1, n)]
    # create the problem
    prob = LpProblem('TSP-MTZ', LpMinimize)
    # create add the objective function 
    objective_function = lpSum( [ lpSum([xij*cj if xij != None else 0 for (xij, cj) in zip(brow, crow) ])
                           for (brow, crow) in zip(binary_vars, cost_matrix)] )
    
    prob += objective_function 
    
    # add the degree constraints
    for i in range(n):
        # Exactly one leaving variable
        prob += lpSum([xj for xj in binary_vars[i] if xj != None]) == 1
        # Exactly one entering
        prob += lpSum([binary_vars[j][i] for j in range(n) if j != i]) == 1
    # add time stamp constraints
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if i == j: 
                continue
            xij = binary_vars[i][j]
            ti = time_stamps[i-1]
            tj = time_stamps[j -1]
            prob += tj >= ti + xij - (1-xij)*(n+1) # add the constraint
    # Done: solve the problem
    status = prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False)) # turn off messages
    assert status == constants.LpStatusOptimal, f'Unexpected non-optimal status {status}'
    # Extract the tour
    tour = [0]
    tour_cost = 0
    while len(tour) < n:
        i = tour[-1]
        # find all indices j such that x_ij >= 0.999 
        sols = [j for (j, xij) in enumerate(binary_vars[i]) if xij != None and xij.varValue >= 0.999]
        assert len(sols) == 1, f'{sols}' # there better be just one such vertex or something has gone quite wrong
        j = sols[0] # extract the lone solutio 
        tour_cost = tour_cost + cost_matrix[i][j] # add to the tour cost
        tour.append(j) # append to the tour
        assert j != 0
    i = tour[-1]
    tour_cost = tour_cost + cost_matrix[i][0]
    return tour, tour_cost
```

Now I'm trying to implement k_tsp_mtz_encoding(n, k, cost_matrix) which  return a list lst that has exactly  k  lists in it, wherein lst[j] represents the locations visited by the jth  salesperson but I'm not sure what to do. Guidance on this would be appreciated.